# why am I getting unreachable statement error in java code. need help to solve this error

Tags: java

Below is the commented line, where I'm getting an unreachable error:

```
    public class HotelRoom{
        private int rNo;
        private int dRented;
        private String rType;
        private String occName;

**type of accomodation is checked below**
    if(rType=="king"){ this.rType=rType; }
    else if(rType=="queen"){ this.rType=rType;}
    else if(rType=="suite"){ this.rType=rType;}
    else{this.rType = "queen"; } }
**accessor** 
    public int getRoomNumber(){ return rNo; }
    public int getDaysRented(){ return dRented; }
**mutator**
    public String getRoomType(){ return rType; }
    public String getOccupantName(){return occName; }
**setting the value of occupant based on the conditions**
    public boolean setOccupant(String guestName, int days){
    if(this.occName!=null){ return false; }
    this.occName=guestName; this.dRented = days; return true; }
```

**advance method**

```
public void advanceDay(){
        this.dRented = this.dRented - 1;
        if(this.dRented <= 0){ this.occName = null; this.dRented = 0;}}
```

toString method:

```
public String toString(){String out = "";

if(occName!=null){out = "Rented"; return out;}
else{ out ="Free"; return out;}
```

**Error line** -"unreachable error":

return "HotelRoom" + rNo +":" + rType + "-" + out;
}

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        HotelRoom r1 = new HotelRoom(007,"king");
        System.out.println(r1);
        }
        }
```

Comment: You are returning from your method in the `if` and in the `else` , there is no way that subsequent statements are reachable.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm really new to this. if you dont mind can you please tell me where exactly i've to change.  so that based on the condition of the occupant i can get the output in the main method.

Comment: See below answers :)

Comment: I have a vague feeling that your source code in your editor does not look like what you put within your question here. If I am wrong, and your input here matches what you have in your editor, I suggest you get yourself a book and study about valid java syntax first.

Comment: Besides, you are comparing `String`s with `==` never do that.

Comment: @GhostCat Not at all, it looks good in my editor, clean and Indented.Thanks for the link, much appreciated.

Comment: I am talking about the * * chars all over the place?!

Answer (score 0):

The method `toString` (that I report here reformatted for readable reasons):

```
public String toString() {
  String out = "";
  if (occName != null) {
    out = "Rented"; 
    return out;  // Exit here
  } else { 
    out ="Free"; 
    return out;  // or exit here
  }
  // Never reachable
  return "HotelRoom" + rNo +":" + rType + "-" + out;
}
```

the last row is never reachable because you return from the previous `if` block and **also** in the `else` block, so there is no chance to reach the last line.

I suppose that you like the following behaviour:

```
public String toString() {
  String out = "";
  if (occName != null) {
    // Just set out variable
    out = "Rented"; 
  } else { 
    // Just set out variable
    out ="Free"; 
  }
  // Return a complete string using the previous out variable
  return "HotelRoom" + rNo +":" + rType + "-" + out;
}
```

---

A tip: format always your code so that it is more human readable. A code that is easy to read is also a code that is easy to study to find errors.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer!!! came across the stackover error - as it was not allowing me to post the question because of the formatting issue, so I wasted hell lot of time formatting each and every line. sorry If the code is not readable, I hope Ill do better next time.

Comment: @JohnDoe To format it: 1 - copy  your code from your IDE, 2 - Paste the code to stackoverflow, 3 - Highlight the code, 4 - Click the button {} Code Sample, it will mantain the formatting of your ide.

Comment: I did the same thing, googled a lot as well. But still this error didn't go at all -->"Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)."  I am unable to ask new question because I posted the un-readable code. well, this is new to me. Ill learn and get back. But anyways thanks a lot for the solutions